# Convert list of IP's into CIDR blocks

Tags: python

I would like to take a list of IPv4 addresses like so and convert them to a list of summarized CIDR, with the closest matching IP addresses grouped together to create the CIDR block.

My understanding based on the link below is that I want to convert these into a list of ranges using `itertools.groupby()` and then turn them into a CIDR based off the ranges.

I am having issues with the `lambda` part of the [example from another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47042026/python-generate-ip-ranges-from-list-of-ip-addresses). Which I think is crucial to creating the ranges.

**Lambda Error** (something to do with not being able to do unpacking?)

```py
<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

My List of IP addresses:

```py
ip_addresses = [
    216.144.250.150,
    69.162.124.226,
    69.162.124.227,
    69.162.124.228,
    69.162.124.229,
    69.162.124.230,
    69.162.124.231,
    69.162.124.232,
    69.162.124.233,
    69.162.124.234,
    69.162.124.235,
    69.162.124.236,
    69.162.124.237,
    63.143.42.242,
    63.143.42.243,
]
```

My current function running on Python 3.9.6:

```py
def create_range(ip_addresses):
    groups=[]
    for _, g in itertools.groupby(enumerate(sorted(ip_addresses)), lambda i,x:i-int(x)):
        group = map(operator.itemgetter(1), g)
        if len(group) > 1:
           groups.append("{}-{}".format(group[0], str(group[-1]).split('.')[-1]))
        else:
           groups.append(str(group[0]))
    return groups
```

Comment: Check out the [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module.

Comment: Take a look at the [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) standard module. I guess it will make your life easier.

Comment: I guess your list is actually made of strings representing IPv4 addresses, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using the standard library [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module:

```py
import ipaddress

ips = [
    '216.144.250.150',
    '69.162.124.226',
    '69.162.124.227',
    '69.162.124.228',
    '69.162.124.229',
    '69.162.124.230',
    '69.162.124.231',
    '69.162.124.232',
    '69.162.124.233',
    '69.162.124.234',
    '69.162.124.235',
    '69.162.124.236',
    '69.162.124.237',
    '63.143.42.242',
    '63.143.42.243',  
]

# First, let's convert the string objects into IPv4Address objects
ips = [ipaddress.IPv4Address(_) for _ in ips]

# Now we can summarize them
cidrs = list(ipaddress.collapse_addresses(ips))
```

The code snippet above will leave `cidrs` with the following contents:

```py
[
    IPv4Network('63.143.42.242/31'), 
    IPv4Network('69.162.124.226/31'),
    IPv4Network('69.162.124.228/30'),
    IPv4Network('69.162.124.232/30'),
    IPv4Network('69.162.124.236/31'),
    IPv4Network('216.144.250.150/32')
]
```