Sorting a list of IP addresses into unique network address with the ranges of host addresses
I have a list of IP addresses from an API call:
ips = ["10.135.0.80","10.135.0.81","10.135.0.83","10.135.1.200","10.135.1.220","10.160.150.2","10.160.150.7","10.255.255.2"]

I want to have a list of IP addresses that looks like:
ips = ["10.135.0.80-10.135.0.83","10.135.1.200-10.135.1.220","10.160.150.2-10.160.150.7","10.255.255.2-10.255.255.2"]

Or a result based on the suggested answer:
ips = [("10.135.0.80", "10.135.0.83"),("10.135.1.200", "10.135.1.220"),("10.160.150.2", "10.160.150.7"),("10.255.255.2","10.255.255.2")]

If the network address is equal join the smallest to largest host address.
If there is one host address per network address create a range out of said host address.
If the network address is different start a new element and repeat.
I've read a number of other posts where they say to use socket module and bitwise operators to sort through IP addresses which is how the original IP list gets sorted:
sortedAddresses = sorted(
    ips, key=lambda ip: struct.unpack("!L", inet_aton(ip))[0]
)

The networks I can smash together really easy with some regex and make them all unique:
net = []
host = []
for ip in sortedAddresses:
    l = re.split("(.*)\\.(.*)\\.(.*)\\.(.*)", ip)
    net.append(l[1:-2])
    host.append(l[4:-1])
networks = []
for l in net:
    if l not in networks:
        networks.append(l)
hosts = []
for l in host:
    for e in l:
        hosts.append(e)
print(networks)
print(hosts)

Print Networks:
[['10', '135', '0'], ['10', '135', '1'], ['10', '160', '150'], ['10', '255', '255']]
Print Hosts:['80', '81', '83', '200', '220', '2', '7', '2']
I think Joran's answer here with the socket module is the closest thing I've found to being my solution. I just can't figure out how I would sort through the list of hosts to determine the start and end in my original list or hosts list.
The suggested answer I received before posting is close as well except it would create to many ranges. I want the network addresses to be unique per range.

Why do you have 80-83 when the input doesn't contain 82.

@wim Because the network address is the same on all three host addresses. I don't care if the host address doesn't technically exist in the list.

you assume all networks are /24?

re.split("(.*)\\.(.*)\\.(.*)\\.(.*) sooo just split(".")

@leo They are not no. Assume they are interfaces, so /32. I tried a number of times with netaddr and ipaddress modules but to avail. I just need to play around with the int > ip and ip > int part of bitwise operators in code more to avoid having to use regex.

The folowing code:
import itertools

ips = [
    "10.135.0.80",
    "10.135.0.81",
    "10.135.0.83",
    "10.135.1.200",
    "10.135.1.220",
    "10.160.150.2",
    "10.160.150.7",
    "10.255.255.2",
]
for _, v in itertools.groupby(ips, lambda v: v.split(".")[:3]):
    v = sorted(list(v), key=lambda x: int(x.split(".")[3]))
    low = v[0]
    high = v[-1]
    print(f"{low}-{high}")

outputs:
10.135.0.80-10.135.0.83
10.135.1.200-10.135.1.220
10.160.150.2-10.160.150.7
10.255.255.2-10.255.255.2


WOW! That worked. I tried something similar to this answer, but the answer was very python 2 so it didn't work well.
for _, g in itertools.groupby(enumerate(ips), lambda (i,x):i-int(x)): 
He had that in his first line. His lambda errors out in my python code.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47042026/python-generate-ip-ranges-from-list-of-ip-addresses Here is the post with the answer similar to yours but for some reason it didn't work well in python 3.

if you could please update your answer without your sorted and with my sorted list first. Your sorted list in v=sorted(list(v) causes some IPs to become missed. For example, if the first IP is .4, .9 they were missed, and the range would be 10.135.0.10-10.135.0.99. After accessing my sorted list and removing your sorted the result was 10.135.0.4-10.135.0.250 which is correct and now works on all unique network addresses.

I think as i understand it is that's because it sorts alphabetically, not numerically.
